# Trouble moving files against a blacklist in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Hey guys I'm trying to move all files from one directory to another that are not contained in a blacklist, I'm getting the error `missing destination file after operand after $SVN` also included is some of the the debugger info, thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear; set -x

# here
ROOT=`pwd`

# dirs
SVN_FOLDER="${ROOT}/svn"
GIT_FOLDER="${ROOT}/git"

# blacklist
EXCLUDE=('.git' '.idea')
EXCLUDELIST=$(printf "|%s" "${EXCLUDE[@]}")
EXCLUDEDIR=`echo "${GIT_FOLDER}/!(${EXCLUDELIST:1})"`

shopt -s dotglob nullglob # see hidden

mv $EXCLUDEDIR $SVN_FOLDER

  # + mv {dir}/svn   <--- the excluded stuff is NOT in the MV cmd?
  # mv: missing destination file operand after ‘{dir}/svn’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll solve it this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

SVN_FOLDER="${ROOT}/svn"
GIT_FOLDER="${ROOT}/git"

EXCLUDE=('.git' '.idea')
EXCLUDE_PATTERN=$(IFS='|'; echo "${EXCLUDE[*]}")
EXCLUDE_PATTERN=${EXCLUDE_PATTERN//./\\.}

find "$GIT_FOLDER" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-egrep -not -regex ".*/(${EXCLUDE_PATTERN})$" -exec mv -i -t "$SVN_FOLDER" '{}' '+'
```

If the command works for you already, you can optionally remove `-i` option from the `mv` command.

Comment: Seems to be taking all the files with it, i'll post a pastebin in a min so you can see whats going on

Comment: @ehime I made an update. I should have added a semicolon between `echo` and `IFS`.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's “inefficient”, but unless you're moving a vast number of files regularly, what's wrong with something simple and expedient like:

```
blacklist=/tmp/black.lst
srcdir=foo
dstdir=bar

for f in $srcdir/*; do
    if !fgrep -qs "$f" $blacklist; then
        mv $f $dstdir
    fi
done
```

Or, how about this. I'll bet it knocks the socks off anything else in speed terms by hard-linking instead of copying content:

```
#!/bin/bash

root=$(pwd)
svn_dir=$root/svn
git_dir=$root/git
blacklist='.git .idea'
exclude='--exclude .svn'
for f in $blacklist; do
    exclude="$exclude --exclude $f"
done

if ! [ -e $svn_dir ]; then
    cp -al $git_dir $svn_dir
    for f in $blacklist; do
        rm -rf $svn_dir/$f
    done
fi

rsync -a $exclude $git_dir/ $svn_dir
```

Comment: I will be, this script will be running GIT revision checkouts, copying over the contents to a SVN folder, and SVN committing them, currently I'm at over 10k revisions, and I'm expecting it be moving a few thousand files/dirs at a time every few seconds =( Plus one for you though =)

Comment: looks like the above removes `$svn_dirs` .svn folder, I DO like the rsync solution though. The problem is, that rsync doesn't realize that there already is a folder inside svn_dir, and proceeds to overwrite the entire directory

Comment: @ehime: ah, I see. I never thought of that. You could certainly do it with moderately more elaborate `rsync` filtering. Adding `.svn` to the blacklist and omitting the `--delete-excluded` should prevent `rsync` from touching the `.svn` directory. But then you'd have to put in an `rm` for the other elements of the blacklist immediately after the initial copy.

Comment: @ehime, well, I've made changes that kinda-sorta reflect what I think you want, but I still don't know how the `.svn` directory gets into `$svn_dir` if it starts off as a carbon-copy of `$git_dir` which (presumably) doesn't have a `.svn` directory in it.

Answer (score 0):

How about find?

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.git' ! -name '.idea' -exec mv {} $DEST \;
```